# Travis Failing because The log length has exceeded the limit of 4 MB

Tags: cmake, travis-ci

Is there a way to reduce the verbosity of the command:

```
INSTALL( DIRECTORY ${STAN_INCLUDE_DIR_STAN_MATH} DESTINATION include/s/lib/external/Stan )
INSTALL( DIRECTORY ${STAN_INCLUDE_DIR_BOOST} DESTINATION include/s/lib/external/Stan_Boost )
INSTALL( DIRECTORY ${STAN_INCLUDE_DIR_CVODES} DESTINATION include/s/lib/external/Stan_Cvodes )
```

Once I added it, Travis fails because its generating too much logs. It basically adds a new line:

```
-- Installing: /home/travis/s-build/include/s/lib/external/<link to a file>
```

Is there a way to cancel this verbosity from the Install command so that it doesn't log a new line for every file it installs?

Answer (score 0):

Simple use output redirection.

```
cmake --build . #build and show log.
cmake --build . --target install > /dev/null   #install and discard stdout
```